# gnuplot rowstacked : Sum of rows is alway 100 but on the graphic bar are less than 100

Tags: gnuplot

I try to represent a budget with gnuplot with rowstacked histograms.

Here is my script

```
#Ce fichier permet de plotter les dépenses et les récettes sur une même image
#Les fichiers des données sont structurées comme suit
#Sur la première ligne qui commence par un croisillon suivi d'une espace, les textes des libellés. Les espaces à l'intérieur des libellés sont insécables
#Sur la deuxième ligne qui commence par un croisillon suivi d'une espace les valeurs en euros
#Sur la troisième ligne, le total de la section
#Sur la quatrième ligne les valeurs en pourcentage

#Dans un terminal, se placer dans le dossier où se trouve ce fichier, entrer la commande gnuplot
# puis au prompt de gnuplot taper : call "InvestissementRowStacked.gnu" "Fonctionnement" "2017" "545 000"



set decimalsign ','
unset multiplot
unset ylabel
set term pngcairo size 2048,800
set output ARG1.'.png'


#Le titre est commun aux deux plots

set multiplot title "Budget primitif - ".ARG1." ".ARG2." (Total ".ARG3." €)" font 'Arial,18'

#réglages communs aux deux plots
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set boxwidth 2 absolute
set style fill solid border


#unset xtics
#unset ytics

#####################################
#DÉPENSES
######################################

#place le premier plot et le limite à la moitié de la largeur
set origin 0.01,0.05
set size 0.49,0.9

#titre pour le premier plot
set title "Dépenses" font 'Arial,16'

file ="Dépenses".ARG1.ARG2.".dat"
#regarde le nombre de données
unset xrange
unset yrange
stats file output
n=STATS_columns 

set yrange [0:120]

#lit les valeurs en pourcentage sur la troisième ligne du fichier
getData(fName, row)=system(sprintf("sed -n -e %dp %s", row, fName))

values = getData(file, 3)

#lit les valeurs en euros sur la deuxième ligne
values2= getData(file, 2)


#utilise la première ligne pour les libellés 
names=system(sprintf("head -1 '%s'",file))

#calcule le point d'arrivée des flèches en ordonnées
cumul_D=0
f(x)=(cumul_D=cumul_D+x, cur_D=cumul_D-x/2., cur_D)

#supprime la légende
unset key

#plot les dépenses avec les libellés et les flèches sur la gauche

set xrange [-14:2]
plot for [C=1:n] sprintf('%s',file) u C, \
for [C=1:n] sprintf('%s',file) u (-3.8):(2+9*C):(+2.8):(f(column(C))-2-9*C) w vectors lc rgb('black'), \
for [C=1:n] sprintf('%s',file) u (-4):(2+9*C):(word(names,C+1).' ('.word(values,C).'% | '.word(values2,C+1).' €) ') w labels right font 'Arial,14'

######################
# RECETTES
#######################

#plot les recettes avec les libellés et les flèches sur la droite

fileR ="Recettes".ARG1.ARG2.".dat"

#regarde le nombre de données
unset yrange
unset xrange
stats fileR output
n=STATS_columns 
set yrange [0:120]
set xrange [-2:14]


set title "Recettes" font 'Arial,16'

#lit les valeurs en pourcentage dans la troisième ligne du fichier
values = getData(fileR, 3)

#lit les valeurs en euros sur la deuxième ligne du fichier
values2=getData(fileR, 2)

#utilise la première ligne pour les libellés
names=system(sprintf("head -1 '%s'",fileR))

#place le deuxième plot dans la seconde moitié en largeur du canvas
set origin 0.5,0.05
set size 0.49,0.9

#réinitialise le calcul des points d'arrivée des flèches de libellé
cumul_D=0

#plot les recettes avec les flèches et les libellés à droite


plot for [C=1:n] sprintf('%s',fileR) u C, \
for [C=1:n] sprintf('%s',fileR) u (3.8):(2+9*C):(-2.8):(f(column(C))-2-9*C) w vectors lc rgb('black'), \
for [C=1:n] sprintf('%s',fileR) u (4):(2+9*C):('('.word(values,C).'% | '.word(values2,C+1).' €) '.word(names,C+1)) w labels left font 'Arial,14'

unset multiplot; set output
```

the budget has two sections Investissement and Fonctionnement and I use the following command to plot the sections

```
call "BudgetRowStacked.gnu" "Fonctionnement" "2017" "460 000"
```

and

```
call "BudgetRowStacked.gnu" "Investissement" "2017" "545 000"
```

I get the following

[image]
[image]

There are some strangeness I have trouble to explain. 
The bars doesn't reach 100 despite the fact that the sum of the data is always 100, moreover, in the Investissement section, the bars are of different heights.

Comment: Using . instead of , in my values solves the problem. The question is how to have it working in my locale "fr"

Answer (score 0):

I solved every thing using

```
set locale 'fr_FR'
set decimalsign locale
```